# How to embed an if statement in a "for of" loop in JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a genuine quetion. Given this simple JS code:

```
for (let x of array) {
   if (x != array[0]) {
       // do stuff
   }
}
```

Is there a way to embed the "if" statement **directly** into the for loop?

I tried something like this:

```
for (let x of array if x != array[0] {
   // do stuff    
}
```

And:

```
for (let x != array[0] of array) {
   // do stuff
}
```

But both of them didn't work. Let me know if you can find a solution!

Comment: No, there is not. For iterating arrays in particular, @Spectric's answer with `.filter()` comes closest

Comment: @Bergi Nice to know, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can filter the array with the condition and iterate through that result:

```js
const array = [1, 2, 3]

for(let x of array.filter(e => e != array[0])){
    console.log(x)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cant pass a boolean in a "for of" or "for in" loops , the only way of do a comparison for an iteration of a loop is doing :

```
let array = ["37","728"];

for (let x = 0 ; ((x < array.length) && array[x] == "37") ; x++){
  console.log(array[x]);
}
```

And it will break the for loop if the second condition pass to true

Answer (score 1):

If you specifically only want to do stuff on the 2nd - nth element, you can just use a for loop and start at 1 instead of 0.

```js
for (let i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
  // do stuff
}
```

Comment: This would make a comment to the question. I don't see it try to answer `Is there a way to embed the "if" statement directly into the for loop?`

Comment: You're right, I completely misread the question - oops.